# IIS 7 and SSL wildcard certificate

Tags: ssl, iis-7

I have an unsecured domain and want to create a secured sub-domain. On the same IP address running Windows Server 2008 and IIS 7.

So I've purchased a wildcard SSL certificate for *.mydomain.co.uk and installed it fine on the server. It appears under the server certificates correctly.

I've set up the subdomain with a HTTP binding for testing purposes and everything works fine - so it's not a problem with IIS. I then add an HTTPS binding for the subdomain on the normal 443 port and because I've named the certificate *.mydomain.com, the hostnames box is enabled for me in the UI. So I setup the HTTPS binding, remove the HTTP binding, restart the website and IIS. When I browse to www.mydomain.com that works fine - but when I browse to https://subdomain.mydomain.com I get a browser fault saying it can't find the server.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK figured it out - as normal it was a multitude of problems not just one.

First was a firewall issue - the server is running on Amazon EC2 and the security group was set up to block HTTPS traffic on port 443.

Second up was indeed the DNS. Although the sub-domain was browsable WITHOUT a CNAME record when using HTTP binding, an explicit CNAME record seems to be required when using HTTPS. Don't ask me why.

The sub-domain in question is for an IFrame Facebook app. It rendered fine in IE and Chrome but Firefox threw up the ssl_error_renegotiation_not_allowed error. This was due to the SSL settings in IIS - they need to be set to Require SSL (unticked) or ticked but then Client Certificates to Ignore

Phew - glad it's up and running now.

Answer (score 0):

Check your DNS setup and make sure you've got an A or CNAME record for subdomain.mydomain.com.

Just having your webserver set up to handle a particular domain name doesn't mean the hostname/domain actually exists - the DNS system must be configured for it as well.

Comment: Agreed. If you don't have any A record, or for that matter, any entry in your DNS system for the sub-domain you will not be able to reach your sub-domain site. IIS setup is only half the process.

Comment: But the DNS works. If the subdomain is set up using an http binding rather and an https binding it works fine. Browsers can get to it etc. Do I need to do anything different just because it's an https?

Comment: Should add that the DNS is working from externally to the server. i.e. normally internet connected PC can browser to the sub-domain if set up using HTTP binding. It's when changing it to an HTTPS binding that things break.

Comment: dns doesn't care at all what protocol you're using. It's not possible to map a hostname to 2 different ips based on if you're using http for one and https for the other. if you can't reach the hostname via https, then it's a webserver config issue. if you can't ping/nslookup the hostname at ALL from wherever you're running the browser, then it's a dns issue.

Comment: I agree, this shouldn't have anything to do with DNS. DNS is the issue, when you can't access the hostname at all.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this with A records not CNAME. I do not have require SSL ticked.  I used URL rewrite instead.
`<rule name="redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="http://(.*)"/>
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent"/>
        </rule>`

You also need to setup SSL Host Headers on all secure subdomains using the wildcard certificate.

```
appcmd set site /site.name:"<IISSiteName>" /+bindings.[protocol='https',bindingInformation='*:443:<hostHeaderValue>']
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be a pain to figure this one out, but one thing to look for is

But make sure that the identity for the app pool used for the subdomain has permissions to the C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys  folder.

Comment: Hi @Dimestore, what do you mean by "identity for the app pool used for the subdomain" can you give me an exact idea, how to do this?

Comment: Do you mean to say this? http://waissguy.wordpress.com/2010/08/30/granting-permissions-to-the-applicationpoolidentity/

Comment: Don't know if late answer will help anyone, I meant that the app pool used for the site has a windows identity, that identity must have file read permissions for the MachineKeys folder.  Usually an identity set up to be used for an App Pool is not set up to have read access for that folder (or any folder outside of the site)